# Promise returning a function instead of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, es6-promise

I am using the node module `fbgraph` in order to retrieve data from a Facebook user and create an account in our app.

I have the following code which is wrapped inside an async function:

```
const newUser = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  graph.get(url, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    }

    const user = new User();
    user.firstName  = res.first_name;
    user.lastName   = res.last_name;
    user.email      = res.email;

    return resolve(user);
  });
});

this.register(newUser);
```

I am unable to pass the `newUser` variable to my register function, and am getting this error:

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
```

Upon logging `newUser`, it appears to be the correct `User` object I am expecting, but when I log `newUser.constructor` it appears that what's actually being returned is a `[Function: User]`

I'm not particularly experienced with Promises, and I feel like the problem lies somewhere there. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `newUser.constructor` should point to `User` so the output seems correct?

Comment: `newUser.constructor` is pointing towards `[Function: User]` instead of an actual `User` and I don't know why

Comment: `newUser.constructor` returns the function where as `newUser.constructor.name` returns the name of class

Comment: ? `someObject.constructor` always points to the constructor function that created `somObject`. `[Function: User]` just seems to be a nice output for a function that has the name User .

Comment: Oh, I see. I've also tried logging `newUser.firstName` and its attributes, but these errors keep popping up: `[ts] Property 'firstName' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Comment: I don't know how typescript works but it seems that it doesn't know the type of the value the promise resolves to, so you might have to add type annotations for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript cannot infer actual promise type, so defaults to something - in this case `{}`.

You should be explicit about `Promise` and create `Promise<User>` type i.e

```
const newUser = await new Promise<User>((resolve, reject) => {
    //...
})
```